# QuickTime Player won't save compress file

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, quicktime

I am using the following setup:

- macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- QuickTime Player 10.5
- MacBook Pro (M1, 13-inch, 2020)

I've compressed an MP4 movie file in QuickTime Player Version 10.5.

When I try to export the compressed file, I get the following error below:

> “The operation could not be completed An unknown error…”

What would cause this error? How can it be solved?

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to save it?

Comment: I have tried to save it under two directories. One is Document and second is Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Quit QuickTime Player and try clearing preferences. You can do this by navigating to `~/Library/Preferences` and removing the `com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.plist` file.

Commander One simplifies file operations on macOS. Try using it for managing your video files and see if the issue persists.